# Does an application running via Citrix listen on local interfaces?

Tags: citrix

Let's say you have an application that listens on a socket on all network interfaces on a machine and displays the messages it receives on a UI. If I run this application on a client machine via Citrix (Presentation Server?) would the application also be listening on the network interfaces available on the client machine by default. If not is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the application via Citrix, it is executed on the Citrix (XenApp / Presentation) Server and listens **on the server**.

If you would rather have the application listen **on the client** but be executed on the server, you could use the virtual channel SDK to pass data between the server and the client. You can find more information in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389062/sending-message-to-citrix-session/4391595#4391595).